# converting timedeltas to integer values in pandas

Tags: pandas, timedelta

I've read  many topics here and tried many different things but it did not work somehow. 
Basically, I have a field called order_date which was "object" initially. I've converted it to datetime64[ns] by applying this function :

```
customer_data['order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(customer_data['order_date'])
```

Now, I'd like to calculate the difference between two timedeltas and get an integer value like this :

```
customer_data['recency']= (customer_data.order_date.max() - customer_data['order_date'])
```

But when I do this, I want my new column "recency" to be an INTEGER value rather than a timedelta64[ns] . Any idea how to do this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) with casting to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
customer_data['recency'] = customer_data['recency'].dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
```

Sample:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10)
customer_data = pd.DataFrame({'order_date': rng, 'a': range(10)})  
#print (customer_data)

customer_data['recency']= (customer_data.order_date.max() - customer_data['order_date'])
customer_data['recency'] = customer_data['recency'].dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
print (customer_data)
   a order_date  recency
0  0 2017-04-03   777600
1  1 2017-04-04   691200
2  2 2017-04-05   604800
3  3 2017-04-06   518400
4  4 2017-04-07   432000
5  5 2017-04-08   345600
6  6 2017-04-09   259200
7  7 2017-04-10   172800
8  8 2017-04-11    86400
9  9 2017-04-12        0
```

Another solution with [`dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
customer_data['recency'] = customer_data['recency'].dt.days.astype(int)
print (customer_data)
   a order_date  recency
0  0 2017-04-03        9
1  1 2017-04-04        8
2  2 2017-04-05        7
3  3 2017-04-06        6
4  4 2017-04-07        5
5  5 2017-04-08        4
6  6 2017-04-09        3
7  7 2017-04-10        2
8  8 2017-04-11        1
9  9 2017-04-12        0
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael but the result is like 72144000.0 which is not what I want. I just want to see the day differences between two timedeltas as an INTEGER value

Comment: Is possible some `NaN`s values?

Comment: When I use the formula you've provided like this : customer_data['recency']= (customer_data.order_date.max() - customer_data['order_date']).dt.total_seconds().fillna(0).astype(int)   I'm still getting a result like 72144000 which is not what I want :( I'm really pissed now, this shouldn't be that difficult....

Comment: Actually, I think my problem is to get rid of the "time" part of the timedeltas first and then convert it to INTEGER values. Because as you see in your output, I see very big numbers for recency which is not what I want.

Comment: Glad can help, nice day!